# .htaccess: rewrite rules not working as I'd like

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

*Sorry in advance for non technical terms; but keep in mind I really tried a lot to find a solution before posting here.*

Under webroot folder i've 2 websites; these are the entry points:

```
/frontend/web/index.php
/backend/web/index.php
```

My goal is

- Access `/frontend/web/index.php` opening `http://domain.tld`
- Access `/backend/web/index.php` opening `http://domain.tld/something`

This is my `webroot/.htaccess`

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^something
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/something$ backend/web/$1 [L]
```

In this way, `domain.tld/` is opening `/frontend/web` (GOOD), but *also* `domain.tld/something` is pointing to `frontend/web/index.php` instead of `backend/web/index.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The leading slash is removed from the URI when used to match rules in an htaccess file. That means this regex:

```
^(.*)/something$
```

will never match a URI that looks like:

```
something/...
```

Try changing the regex to:

```
RewriteRule ^something(.*)$ backend/web$1 [L]
```